# FQL Stream returns less results than FQL Status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm testing results out with two queries that try to find my friends post based upon the text in the message. The first query:

```
select uid, status_id, message, time, source FROM status where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND (strpos(lower(message),"father") >=0 );
```

Returns the results that I want, works fine. The second query however which is supppose to be more open because it uses the stream, gets back nothing.

```
SELECT type, created_time, post_id, comments, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me()) AND actor_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND (strpos(lower(message),"father") >=0 );
```

Why is stream returning nothing but status does? Am I missing something?

Comment: This won't solve your problem 100%, but I did notice that in your second query you mention "comments" and that does not exist in the stream.

Comment: And, one other thing. If you change "comments" to "comment_info" and then remove the AND(strpos(lower(message), "father")) >=0 ) from the end of the query you will get results from the query.  The problem must be something in the last bit.